# Pasting from Excel into multiple fields in a webpart

Tags: web-part, copy-and-paste

We have a webpart that has the below section

[image]
We want to be able to copy a column in Excel and paste it into the `Marks Obtained` column.

What should I change in my webpart to do that?

Can I do that without changing the code?

Comment: No, you won't be able to do that, unless you write some (perhaps) javascript code to parse/split the copied text into your multiple fields

Comment: I found a way to do that in this forum: http://www.codingforums.com/javascript-programming/342525-pasting-excel-into-multiple-fields-form.html#post1450699

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer in this forum:
http://www.codingforums.com/javascript-programming/342525-pasting-excel-into-multiple-fields-form.html#post1450699

Comment: Please do not only post a link as an answer, add the relevant parts from tehe link to your post to make it easy to understand the solution and also to make the answer still helpful if the link breaks